# I see that the Bing Skill doesn't work, when invoked from Cortana Channel

Tags: c#, botframework, cortana, bing-search

Skill doesn't respond to any questions asked from the Cortana, even though I am able to invoke the skill. While debugging, found it doesn't touch any break point, not even default activity handler.
Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Code: Echo Bot

```
public class EchoBot : ActivityHandler
{
    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var replyText = $"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}";
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(replyText, speak:replyText, inputHint: InputHints.ExpectingInput, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I use an enterprise test account, would that have something to do with Cortana Skill?? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This was a Cortana issue. Microsoft fixed it and code stated to work. Request can now be considered closed